# Is there a way to prevent invalid row range in powerbuilder

Tags: exception, powerbuilder, outofrangeexception

Is there a way to prevent invalid row range in powerbuilder.

```
IF  dw_lista_campanias.GetSelectedRow(0) > 0 AND    dw_lista_campanias.object.est_camp[dw_lista_campanias.GetRow()] = 'EO020' THEN
```

when **dw_lista_campanias.object.est_camp index is 0** an exception is throw.

> Invalid row range at line 193 in ue_opcion4 event of object w_os0210_mantenimiento_campanya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your codes as below:

IF dw_lista_campanias.ROWCOUNT() > 0 THEN
        IF  dw_lista_campanias.GetSelectedRow(0) > 0 AND  dw_lista_campanias.object.est_camp[dw_lista_campanias.GetRow()] = 'EO020' THEN
//PUT YOUR CODE HERE

END IF

END IF

Happy coding ( from pb developer :) )

Answer (score 1):

You could put this statement in a TRY/CATCH block, but I'd think it'd be easier just to capture GetRow() into a variable and test it for 0 (which is a fairly normal state) before using it to access data.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume there is a retrieve. E.g. `ll_rowsrtn = this.retrieve()`.

```
If ll_rowsrtn > 0 then 
    //the getselectedrow script
End if
```

So the command will not execute unless datawindow has greater than 0 rows